# Tagging people in post on facebook using api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

Is tagging  people in facebook api wall post still unavailable?

I was searching for answer for many hours.

I found tons of information about that it is not possible to do that, but maybe these information are outdated...

Have anyone tried? Maybe there is some kind of solution?

Comment: Are you using latest sdk from here? http://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Answer (score -1):

If you use the below code to post on FB wall, you will get an option to tag friends there. like in the picture attached, [image]

```
[FBNativeDialogs
             presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self
             initialText:@"Hello World!"
             image:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringImageURL]]]
             url:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]
             handler:^(FBNativeDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
             }]
```